# find a and b in $a67.9b

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the following problem, $A$ and $B$ are single digits.

> A store sold 72 decks of cards for $\$A67.9B$. Find $A + B$.

Here is as far as I can go: The price of each deck of card should be $\frac{A67.9B}{72}$, and $72=2^3\times 3^2$. How do I find $A$ and $B$ from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with the number in cents, we know that since it's divisible by 72,  it's also divisible by 9. This means that the sum of its digits must be a multiple of 9. (see [Casting out 9s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines))

The sum of the digits is $(A+B+6+7+9) mod 9 = 0$

So we have, simplifying, $(A+B+4) mod 9 = 0$;

The only sum of digits $A+B$ that meets this specification is $A+B = 5$

Comment: Why use 9, not 3. 72 is divisible by 3 too.

Answer (score 3):

The number of cents of the total cost must be divisible by $8$. There is only one thing $B$ can be to make that happen (note that the value of $A$ does not affect whether the total is divisible by $8$).

The number of cents of the total cost must be divisible by $9$. Once you've found $B$, there is only one possible $A$ that allows this.